# Creating a dynamic MKAnnotationView in Swift

Tags: mapkit, ios9, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Currently, I know how to create a MKAnnotationView with a static pin, an image that's added.

Does anyone know, or have any resources, on how to create a pin that would change colors or have a number displayed inside of it that would change depending on information about the business?

For instance, I would like to have a pin be red when the business is closed, and green when the business is open. Maybe even a dollar signs inside of the pin to tell the user how expensive it is.

**EDIT**

I have created a class called `CustomPin` that adopts the `MKAnnotation` protocol. Additionally, I'm not looking to have a custom `MKAnnotationView` image that can change. Does that mean I'll have to add multiple images for the `MKAnnotationView` in an array and have it change the image everytime the details about the business change?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create custom `MKAnnotationView` by simply inheritance. You can use this class to create annotation view from delegate method.

Here is one example.

```
class KDAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    let titleLabel = UILabel()

    convenience init(annotation: MKAnnotation?) {
        self.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "indetifier")
        self.canShowCallout = false
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 75.0, 85.0)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)

        self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)
        self.addSubview(self.titleLabel)
    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 5.0, 5.0)
            frame.size.height = 20.0
        self.titleLabel.frame = frame
    }


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)


        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(rect), y: CGRectGetMinY(rect)))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(rect), y: CGRectGetMinY(rect)))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(rect), y: CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 10.0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(rect) + 5.0, y: CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 10.0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(rect), y: CGRectGetMaxY(rect)))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(rect) - 5.0, y: CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 10.0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(rect), y: CGRectGetMaxY(rect) - 10.0))
        path.closePath()
        UIColor.lightGrayColor().setStroke()
        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        path.stroke()
        path.fill()

    }


    //MARK: - Public Methods
    func setText(text:String) {
        self.titleLabel.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you very much. I awarded you the bounty as well.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do this programmatically. Following code may help you: 
Initialize the pin and give it a type, such as opened, closed, expensive etc.

```
  MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] init...
  newAnnotation.type = @"opened";  // <-- set type in annotation
  [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
```

In your  (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id ) annotation method put a simple check

```
 MapViewAnnotation *mvAnn = (MapViewAnnotation *)annotation;
    if ([mvAnn.type isEqualToString:@"opened"])
    {
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }
    else if ([mvAnn.type isEqualToString:@"closed"])
    {
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }
    else
    {
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorOrange;
    }
```

Comment: How about adding some text inside the pin itself?