# GCD Serial Queue not returning in order

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I don't understand why the second function is returning before the first. Here's my code. I'm missing something simple I think.

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create(nil, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

dispatch_async(queue) {
  self.requestToServer()
  self.sayHello()
    dispatch_async(get_main_queue(), {
        // Update the UI... 
    }
}
```

`requestToServer()` function obviously takes longer than the `sayHello()` function, but shouldn't they execute one at a time with the serial queue that I have created? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does `requestToServer()` run asynchronously?

Comment: It's an NSURLSession, so yes, I'm almost certain it is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the idea of a serial queue. A serial queue guarantees that blocks will be executed in the order you add them. It does not control statements within the same block. The block can end before all its statements have completed.

If I were to describe your block as a railroad branch, it looks like this:

```
     (another queue)  -- requestToServer() ---------------------------
                     /                                  
(serial queue) start ------- sayHello() ----
                                            \
                                (main queue) --- Update the UI
```

`requestToServer()` does not have a chance to finish before you update the GUI.

Instead, rewrite your `requestToServer()` to take a completion handler:

```
func requestToServer{completion: () -> Void) {
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: ...)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
        // check the response from server
        ...

        // when everything is OK, call the completion handler
        completion()
    }
    task.resume()
}

self.requestToServer() {
    self.sayHello()
    dispatch_async(get_main_queue()) {
        // Update the UI... 
    }
}
```

Comment: So, in theory, I can use a regular concurrent queue as long as I have a completion handler?

Comment: A completion handler is something you want to do when the queue has finished. In your case, you want to `sayHello()` and update the UI when `requestToServer()` is done. `requestToServer()` already runs on its own queue. Simply add a completion handler to let it know what to do when the queue ends

Comment: I hate to be a nuisance, but I'm not exactly sure as to how I'd write this completion handler to alert me of when that function is complete.

Comment: I know this is the answer, so I'll mark it as such. I'll just have to get savvy on how to write a completion handler.

Comment: I understand it can be hard to grasp at first, but if you write lots of concurrent code, you will get used to the idea of completion handler very quickly

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sweating it. If it's anything like an anonymous function in node, we're solid.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You saved a life today.

Comment: If writing a few lines of code can save a life, I can write a lot more. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691701/creating-a-dynamic-mkannotationview  maybe you'll have some insight on this question of mine?